# Cannot connect to MySQL datebase

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a clan MySQL database that tracks player stats in a game. There person in charge of our MySQL is away at the moment and we are getting this following Error

```
[18:17:18 23] Error in Tablebuilder:
[18:17:18 23] Message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
[18:17:18 23] Native: -2147467259
[18:17:18 24] Source: MySql.Data
[18:17:18 24] StackTrace: at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnecti onStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnecti on()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at PRoConEvents.CChatGUIDStatsLoggerBF3.tablebuilder( )
[18:17:18 24] InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond    50.63.244.184:3306
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream (IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamFromHost( String pipeName, String hostName, UInt32 timeout)
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
[18:17:18 24] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at PRoConEvents.CChatGUIDStatsLoggerBF3.tablebuilder( )
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Your application was not able to connect to the database.

Comment: Are you sure the ip-address or domain is right?

Comment: If you have nobody around that actually knows their way around MySQL or your codebase, I'm not sure we can help you. My wild guess is that your DB server is down.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading error messages. They look like gibberish but when you read closely, often there is a part it tells you what's going on.

[18:17:18 24] InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond    50.63.244.184:3306

You should now:

1. Execute `telnet localhost 3306` from the database server and if it fails, it's an issue with the DB server
2. Execute `telnet 50.63.244.184 3306` from the application server and if it fails, it's an issue with the network

Comment: SQL query:

EXECUTE telnet localhost3306

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'localhost 3306' at line 1

Comment: @RickyAdams: telnet is a linux command, not a MySQL command

Answer (score 0):

You have two exceptions, them tested, but the meaning is clear:

`"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."`

and

`"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"`

So in short: your webserver cannot connect to you database server. Your database server (the MySQL server process `mysqld.exe` or the server itself, like its OS, hardware, anything) might be stopped. Or the firewall was reset to block connections on the MySQL port 3306. It could be **anything**.

I assume you've got a standard webhost - ping them and ask them why your database server isn't operational.

...but before you embarrass yourself, make sure that your application is connecting to the right server (i.e. production DB, not dev or staging DB). Take a look at your connection string.